# "?." notation in Dart or other Language

Tags: flutter, dart

I am hugely coming across "`?.`" notation in building flutter app.If anyone can help with it .I know"`?:`"operator in other languages.

```
String unmaskedText = _maskedPhoneKey.currentState?.unmaskedText;

_codeTimer?.cancel();
```

Comment: The answer to this is very easy to find with a simple Google search for "Dart operators" -- you'll find the Dart language tour page, and a quick search for `?.` on that page will show you the name of the operator and a description of what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_codeTimer?.cancel();
```

is equivalent to

```
if (_codeTimer != null)
  _codeTimer.cancel();
```

So, you are only calling `cancel()` on `_codeTimer` if it isn't `null`, so it prevents you to check for `null`.

Comment: Also ?? at the end of a binding statement means if it was null then do something else, for example:   `int number = _getNumberFromDb() ?? 0;`

Answer (score -1):

how about such

CameraController? controller and

videoController!.setLooping(true)

Comment: Is this a question or answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).